# NFS mount under another NFS mounted directory's sub-directory

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm a newbie for linux mount system.  So I have a problem with NFS mount.

I have two PC(PC1, PC2) and PC1 has two harddisks(sda1, sdb1)

at PC1, each disk mounted like this

```
/dev/sda1 on /nfsshare type etx4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /nfsshare/more type ext4 (rw)
```

and this is PC1:/etc/exports file

```
#PC1:/etc/exports file
/nfsshare [PC2's IP] (rw, sync, no_root_squash, no_subtree_check)
/nfsshare/more [PC2's IP] (rw, sync, no_root_squash, no_subtree_check)
```

I want to show each of `PC1:/nfsshare` and `PC1:/nfsshare/more` at `PC2`

So I mounted like this

```
mount -t nfs PC1:/nfsshare PC2:/nfs
mount -t nfs PC1:/nfsshare/more PC2:/nfs/more
```

mount done without any problem or warning message

and I can show changes of `PC1:/nfsshare` from `PC2:/nfs`

But I couldn't show any changes of `PC1:/nfsshare/more` from `PC2:/nfs/more`

How could I fix this??  I want to show all of changes included in sub-tree under `PC1:/nfsshare` from `PC2:/nfs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to fix the typo in your exports. You said you have

> /nfsshare/tron [PC2's IP] (rw, sync, no_root_squash, no_subtree_check)

but you intend to export "more" rather than "tron".

Also, consider testing a simpler non-nested mount point, such as "/nfsmore", and then fixing things up with symlinks.

Comment: oh, it's my mis-typing.  /etc/exports exports 'more'.  sorry for that.

Comment: How does the non-nested mount work out on PC2? Often there are a bunch of directories in the top level filesystem that can be shadowed with a set of symlinks pointing at NFS directories.